# How to enable remote debugging in Azure Cloud Service package built by MSBuild

Tags: .net, azure, msbuild, teamcity, azure-cloud-services

I'm building `ccproj` project directly by MSBuild (within TeamCity):

```
msbuild Project.Azure.ccproj /p:Configuration=Debug /t:Publish
```

How to enable remote debugger? Like in the UI:

[image]

Comment: @David: Why are trying to get rid of `azure-cloud-services` tag?

Comment: Only that the tag just started showing up, only 6 questions tagged total out of 12K Azure questions. Didn't really seem valuable for search purposes. But... I've been wrong before. :)

Comment: @DavidMakogon: My point is that each separate Azure technology (at least major Azure block, say - what you see in the Portal left column) may/must have a dedicated tag. Otherwise all Azure-related questions will be tagged just by `azure` what I'm not sure does or does not make any sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [the Azure documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-virtual-machines-dotnet-continuous-delivery-remote-debugging/).

Basically you should get the [remote tools for visual studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40781) and then add the following properties to the msbuild command:

```
msbuild /TARGET:PUBLISH /PROPERTY:Configuration=Debug;EnableRemoteDebugger=true;VSX64RemoteDebuggerPath="<path-to-remote-tools>";RemoteDebuggerConnectorCertificateThumbprint="<thumbprint-of-ceritificate-that-is-added-to-the-cloud-service>";RemoteDebuggerConnectorVersion="2.4" "<path-to-solution-file>"
```

where `VSX64RemoteDebuggerPath` is a path to the folder that contains `msvsmon.exe in the remote tools for visual studio

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is available as a command line switch. I did some searching and only found your question here.

If I do a publish, enabling debugging, in VS 2013 Update 1, it creates a temporary .cscfg file in the output directory along with the package to upload (now almost twice as big). The .cscfg file contains some extra settings:

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Connector.Enabled" value="true" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Connector.Version" value="2.3" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.ClientThumbprint" value="XXXX" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.ServerThumbprint" value="XXXX" />
```

Where XXXX is a thumbprint for a certificate created by VS and installed in the certificate store (My local) with a friendly name of RemoteDebuggerZZZZZ.

An updated .csdef file contains the following section under  for my webrole:

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="https" localPort="443" />
  <InstanceInputEndpoint name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Connector" localPort="30398" protocol="tcp">
    <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      <FixedPortRange min="30400" max="30424" />
    </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
  </InstanceInputEndpoint>
  <InstanceInputEndpoint name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Forwarder" localPort="31398" protocol="tcp">
    <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      <FixedPortRange min="31400" max="31424" />
    </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
  </InstanceInputEndpoint>
</Endpoints>
```

And for my worker role:

```
<Endpoints>
  <InstanceInputEndpoint name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Connector" localPort="30398" protocol="tcp">
    <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      <FixedPortRange min="30425" max="30449" />
    </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
  </InstanceInputEndpoint>
  <InstanceInputEndpoint name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Forwarder" localPort="31398" protocol="tcp">
    <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      <FixedPortRange min="31425" max="31449" />
    </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
  </InstanceInputEndpoint>
</Endpoints>
```

It also added a certificate section for my worker role:

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.TransportValidation" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</Certificates>
```

.. and added the same certificate for my web role:

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="https" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
  <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.TransportValidation" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</Certificates>
```

I have manually added the "https" certificate, so that was there before.

It seems the tooling in VS creates a range of ports to access the ports 30398 and 31398 used by the remote debugging tools and adding the "TransportValidation" certificate to the list of certificates.

There are no extra settings or imports added for either role type.

I have yet to find some documentation on this, so if anybody can shed some light, please do!

Hope this helps anyone else trying this out.

Comment: Looks like what you're describing is defined in `<VS path>\Windows Azure Tools\<Version>\ImportAfter\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.RemoteDebugger.targets` (in particular, in the `ConfigureRemoteDebugger` target). There're some additional steps that might be of interest depending on your situation/requirements.

Answer (score 1):

We've been able to create different profiles for Azure projects per environment. Then we pass in this:

```
/p:TargetProfile=Dev
```

That way it gets built with the correct Cloud Service profile.

Beyond that, I know I would end up just writing some one-off C# or even a Powershell script to modify the config after build.

Comment: Is there a way to save settings such as debug enabled=true|false in cloud environment configuration, i.e. profile? [Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179398.aspx) is really bad.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by debug enabled=true|false. Do you mean remote debugging? Or ... ?

Comment: Yes, how to turn on or off remote debugging using profile config

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem, did you get a resolution?