# New RemoteDebugger Settings in Azure Preventing Build

Tags: c#, azure

I haven't published my cloud service in quite awhile and I am not usually the one to do it as I have taken over a project. When I initially tried to publish it eventually failed and said my settings are probably invalid so I downloaded a new copy of the `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file. The only thing different that I could see is new settings for RemoteDebugging:

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Connector.Enabled" value="true" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.Connector.Version" value="2.3" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.ClientThumbprint" value="X" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteDebugger.ServerThumbprint" ...
```

With the new settings however I am unable to build. It complains that the RemoteDebugger is specified but not declared the ServiceDefinition file.

I thought adding a module would help but it doesn't find it by the name RemoteDebugger. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Imports>
   <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
   <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
   <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
   ...tried a few different possible names here
</Imports>
```

I don't see any way to download this ServiceDefinition file and looking at this post: 
[How to enable remote debugging in Azure Cloud Service package built by MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213054/how-to-enable-remote-debugging-in-azure-cloud-service-package-built-by-msbuild)

...I see a bunch of settings in the ServiceDefinition file that are supposed to be inserted automatically. However I have no idea what these settings should be or how to generate them.